# Unity Connection to web by jsp

Tags: c#, json, jsp, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

public class Network : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("[waitforComm] Hello, World!");

        string postData = "{\"waitforCommData\":1}";
        Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
        headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        byte[] pData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData.ToCharArray());

        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost:8080/jspsample/process.jsp", pData, headers);

        Debug.Log("[waitforComm] post message requested.");

        StartCoroutine(waitforRequest(www));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { }

    private IEnumerator waitforRequest(WWW www)
    {
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log("[waitforComm] response : " + www.text);
    }
}
```

this is our code, i can't figure out this part

WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost:8080/jspsample/process.jsp", pData, headers);

we have error in headers that 
Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Hashtable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'

Comment: It used to be `Hashtable` and that code was once valid but then Unity changed the argument to take `Dictionary` instead in the newer version. [Merk's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44381316/3785314) answer should fix your problem.

Comment: @J.Choi - if any answer solved your problem, accept that as answer which will help others to find the direct answer and save their time :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Unity documentation for the `WWW` object constructor this code is usin](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-ctor.html)g is pretty clear, but not crystal.

The third parameter is declared as `Dictionary<string, string>`, even though the text says "hashtable".

So instead of:

```
Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Do:

```
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: it fixed well. Appreciated it!

Comment: @J.Choi Glad it helped. Please accept the answer when you have a moment.